# Can I make a base class move constructor overload preferable to a derived class copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I have two classes (call them `base` and `derived`) that have an uncommon set of semantics:

- `base` is the parent of `derived`, as you may expect
- `base` is copyable and movable
- `derived` is movable but not copyable
- `base` is not copy-constructible from `derived`

This is all pretty straightforward. I would like, though, for `base` to be move-constructible from `derived`, so I could do something like:

```
derived d;
base b(std::move(d));
```

My attempt at expressing this is as follows:

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct derived;

struct base
{
    base() { }
    base(const derived &) = delete;
    base(const base &) { }
    base(base &&) { }
};

struct derived : base 
{ 
    derived() { }
    derived(const derived &) = delete;
    derived(derived &&) = default;
};

base func()
{
    derived d;
    return std::move(d);
}

int main()
{
    func();
}
```

(I know in a real example I should include the assignment operators too, those are elided for brevity)

However, the above [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/a5Kvdh):

```
<source>: In function 'base func()':
<source>:23:23: error: use of deleted function 'base::base(const derived&)'
   23 |     return std::move(d);
      |                       ^
<source>:8:5: note: declared here
    8 |     base(const derived &) = delete;
      |     ^~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'base func()':
<source>:23:23: error: use of deleted function 'base::base(const derived&)'
   23 |     return std::move(d);
      |                       ^
<source>:8:5: note: declared here
    8 |     base(const derived &) = delete;
      |     ^~~~
```

The compiler is preferring `base`'s deleted constructor from `const derived &`. My intent was that the expression `std::move(d)`, of type `derived &&`, would invoke `base`'s move constructor instead.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: You could include `base(derived &&) { }` in base?   `const T&` is a better match than `U&&` for rvalue of type `T`.

Comment: Please add the c++ tag to C++ questions so that more users will end up seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comment by @M.M above, a solution is to explicitly provide a constructor `base(derived &&)`. I have to do it out-of-line since `derived` is an incomplete type inside `base`, but this works:

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct derived;

struct base
{
    base() { }
    base(const derived &) = delete;
    base(base &&) { }
    base(derived &&);
};

struct derived : base 
{ 
    derived() { }
    derived(const derived &) = delete;
    derived(derived &&) = default;
};

base::base(derived &&d) : 
    base(static_cast<base &&>(d)) { }

base func()
{
    derived d;
    return std::move(d);
}

int main()
{
    func();
}
```